# Does $\mu_k(U \cap \mathbb{R}^k)=0$ for all affine embeddings of $\mathbb{R}^k$ in $\mathbb{R}^n$ imply $\mu_n(U)=0$?

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

Is the following true:

We write $\mu_n$ for the Lebesgue measure on $\mathbb{R}^n$. Let $U \subset \mathbb{R}^n$, $U$ measurable and $k \leq n$. Say for every affine embedding $i \colon \mathbb{R}^k \hookrightarrow \mathbb{R}^n$ we have $\mu_{k}(U \cap i(\mathbb{R^k}))=0$. Does this imply $\mu_n(U)=0$?

Comment: I guess you meant $k<n$ else the conclusion is trivially implied. I also assume that not only *linear* embeddings, i.e. linear subspaces of $\Bbb R^n$ are concerned, but also *affin* subspaces.

Comment: about the $k$: I want to fix one such $k$, optimally $k=1$. Of course, if I fix $k =n$, the question is trivial, if I fix $k>n$ the statement becomes wrong. And yes, I would like not only linear but affine embeddings. I will edit this for clarity.

Comment: For $k=n-1$: don't we have $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\mu_{n-1}(U\cap Z_x)\,dx\ =\ \mu_n(U)$ for a(ny) family of parallel hyperplanes $Z_x$?

Comment: I've not really worked with the Lebesgue measure for 2 years or so, it just happens that the above fact would come in handily right now. Do I see it right, that the case $k=1$ should then follow by induction?

Comment: @Berci: The statement even holds in the case of **linear** embeddings, see my follow-up question here http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/987759/if-u-cap-iota-bbbrk-is-a-k-dimensional-null-set-for-every-linear/.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you changed your question from **linear** embeddings (which was a really interesting question, to which I only know the (positive) answer in the case $k=1$) to affine mappings, the answer is easy:

Simply apply Fubini's Theorem:

\begin{eqnarray*}
\mu_n(U) & =& \int_{\Bbb{R}^n} \chi_U (x) \, d\mu_n (x) = \int_{\Bbb{R}^{n-k}} \int_{\Bbb{R}^k} \chi_U (x,y) d\mu_k (y) d\mu_{n-k} (x)  \\
&=& \int_{\Bbb{R}^{n-k}} \mu_k (\{y \in \Bbb{R}^k \mid (x,y) \in U)\}) d\mu_{n-k}(x) \\
&=& \int_{\Bbb{R}^{n-k}} \mu_k (U \cap \iota_x (\Bbb{R}^k) )\,  d\mu_{n-k}(x) = 0,
\end{eqnarray*}

where $\iota_x (y) = (x,y)$ is an **affine** embedding of $\Bbb{R}^k$ into $\Bbb{R}^n$.

In the above calculation, the last line might not be completely clear. The problem here (as in your question) is that the $k$-dimensional Lebesgue-measure $\mu_k$ is actually only defined on $\Bbb{R}^k$ and not on $\Bbb{R}^n$. Here, I interpret

$$
\mu_k (U \cap \iota (\Bbb{R}^k)) := \mu_k (\iota^{-1}(U)) = \mu_k (\iota^{-1}(U \cap \iota(\Bbb{R}^k))).
$$

This makes the last line true by definition. Also, the actual choice of the embedding $\iota$ does not matter (i.e. the aove definition only depends on the set $\iota(\Bbb{R}^k)$), **as long as you are only interested in null-sets**, basically because there is (up to multiplication by a constant) only **one** translation-invariant measure (Haar-measure) on $\iota(\Bbb{R}^k)$ (when $\iota(\Bbb{R}^k)$ is (by translation) considered as a vector space).